# Celery: all workers stuck, how to diagnose

Tags: celery

Periodically all my Celery workers get stuck on something. I cannot figure out what is causing this, as `inspect` doesn't work as all the workers are busy.

```
  celery inspect active

  Error: No nodes replied within time constraint
```

Is it possible to get Celery status, like active tasks, even if nodes are doing something (that seems to be causing problems)? Can I somehow spin up a temporary worker just to get `inspect` output?

What kind of other strategies there would be to diagnose this issue?

Celery 4.x. Redis backend.

Comment: The question is incomplete, please provide at least your configuration settings for celery and how you run your workers. Is the CPU load high? Are they stuck while executing the tasks or idle? Just a good advice - you can use Redis as a backend, but don't use it as a broker (this might cause the issue you've met). Do you have broker on this same machine or remote (check network)? Check broker logs to find any connection losses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turned out to be a deadlock issue with Celery + gevent (evil monkey patch) + Sentry's Raven logger.

https://github.com/getsentry/raven-python/issues/305

To diagnose issues

You can start Celery workers with different queues (-q, -n) parameters and see when workers hang. Even if some worker groups are hung the others still may respond to `inspect` queries.

Celery file logs may reveal the error

```
2017-02-27 08:36:34,371 CRITI [celery.worker][DummyThread-6] Unrecoverable error: AttributeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'readline'",)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/srv/pyramid/xxx/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/worker/worker.py", line 203, in start
    self.blueprint.start(self)
  File "/srv/pyramid/xxx/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 119, in start
    step.start(parent)
  File "/srv/pyramid/xxx/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 370, in start
    return self.obj.start()
  File "/srv/pyramid/xxx/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 318, in start
    blueprint.start(self)
  File "/srv/pyramid/xxx/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 119, in start
    step.start(parent)
  File "/srv/pyramid/xxx/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 594, in start
    c.loop(*c.loop_args())
  File "/srv/pyramid/xxx/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/worker/loops.py", line 118, in synloop
    connection.drain_events(timeout=2.0)
  File "/srv/pyramid/xxx/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 301, in drain_events
    return self.transport.drain_events(self.connection, **kwargs)
  File "/srv/pyramid/xxx/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kombu/transport/virtual/base.py", line 961, in drain_events
    get(self._deliver, timeout=timeout)
  File "/srv/pyramid/xxx/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kombu/transport/redis.py", line 359, in get
    ret = self.handle_event(fileno, event)
  File "/srv/pyramid/xxx/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kombu/transport/redis.py", line 341, in handle_event
    return self.on_readable(fileno), self
  File "/srv/pyramid/xxx/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kombu/transport/redis.py", line 337, in on_readable
    chan.handlers[type]()
  File "/srv/pyramid/xxx/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kombu/transport/redis.py", line 714, in _brpop_read
    **options)
  File "/srv/pyramid/xxx/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 585, in parse_response
    response = connection.read_response()
  File "/srv/pyramid/xxx/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 577, in read_response
    response = self._parser.read_response()
  File "/srv/pyramid/xxx/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 238, in read_response
    response = self._buffer.readline()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'readline'
```

Comment: thanks alot for posting your resolution! i switched the worker cli from `--pool=eventlet` to `--pool=gevent`, `inspect active` is now responsive, while task is running.

Comment: You are welcome - wow never imagined this would help anyone :)